# Change temporary file location in python webdriver

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I execute my Selenium tests on FF16, Selenium 2.33, Python on Linux. I have created separate firefox profiles corresponding to my devices.

I observed a directory 'webdriver-py-profilecopy' is created in tmp directory. And I see that this directory is deleted after completion of tests. But sometimes these directories are not cleared. The size of this directory is around 28mb. I want to change the tmp directory location.
Is there a way to change temp file location?

In  Java webdriver provides a way to define our own temp directory. Is there a way to do it in Python webdriver
TemporaryFilesystem.setTemporaryDirectory

Answer (score 0):

I used tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='foo',prefix='bar',dir=myTemp) and it worked.

Thanks

Comment: after adding it, still i see 'webdriver-py-profilecopy' dir being created at /tmp.. do we need any other changes ?